# How can learn to make a website(just for practising) without paying for domain and host?

Tags: html, css, networking, web, host

I am learning how to make a website and wondering if it's possible to build my own website just for learning purpose without paying for domain and host? In other words, how can I practise making a website in which I can do almost all things like ones I can do with a real website but I don't have to pay anything?

Comment: run it locally on your machine.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: This is not the place to ask this kind of question. You should get a better assistance posting this at http://superuser.com/

Comment: @JonSurrell I'm using Windows 8.1 :)

Comment: What kind of development do you want to do? Static html, or do you plan to use PHP and MySQL? Will you be using a CMS like WordPress or Drupal?

Comment: @JonSurrell: my goal is to build a website with my web application on it (e.g: a game) or something like website 9gang.com. I've learnt basic of html, css, JS and am confused what to do next. From some sources, I know it could be PHP and MySQL but I'm not sure about it. Is WordPress a suitable and popular choice for my goal? What if I want to build a website without using something like WordPress ( why do people always talk about WordPress, is it very super popular to make a website?)

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create an index.html file, code in there, and then open that file in a web browser like chrome.

As simple as that :)

Comment: If your really new to coding (which I assume here you are), I would use this method as requires no setup other than making a HTML file and opening it in your browser.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the easiest way to start coding.

Comment: thank you guys for your comments, I actually have basic knowledge about HTML,CSS, Javascript. Can you guys recommend me what to do next? I'm so confused which way to go just because there are so many things out there in the Internet. I know trying to discover new things is very good but it would be very appreciated if any of you guys can suggest me a appropriate plan how to learn make a web site (with web application on its or something like social page for sharing eating places). It would save me a lot a time and effort.

Comment: That's quite hard to say... You should learn some CSS techniques like SMACSS or BEM, and jQuery will probably help you out with a lot of things, but it's definetly the answer to everything. Learn Javascript properly reading some books and looking at Mozilla Developer Network. Well, only working experience will teach you the dos and don'ts that you want to discover :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use wamp (windows), or mamp (mac), etc, if you're trying to learn PHP.

There are some others software like SQL server management and IIS for ASP.NET website.

But in case of, learning HTML / CSS / JavaScript can be run on your own machin without any needs. (or txt editor maybe)

You can find somes tuto on internet about "learn html css" or "html / css lessons"

I can recommand you [this website](https://www.codeschool.com/paths/html-css), which help me a lot to start.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've already learnt the basic of HTML, CSS, Javascript/Jquery but I dont know what to learn next (there are so many things that make me confused). My goal is to make my own website that I can not only do what HTML/CSS/JS can do but also do something like making some web applications or a web like 9gang.com, etc. How can I do that without paying anything?

Comment: @MrCold In this case, my opinion would say to learn PHP & MySQL.

For that, search a bit, and WAMP / XAMP / MAMP (depending of your OS) will let you host your website on your computer when you will learn and try.

Answer (score 1):

You can install something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which will render your website files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting with static HTML, CSS and maybe JavaScript later on the way, just create a folder, named e.g. 'myFirstWebsite', in the home directory of your computer, and put a file called index.html into the folder.
Now start hacking! ;)

You can open the file with any browser and it will work. Even JS, embedded in your .html file or in a separate, referenced .js file will execute.

Things get more complicated when you want to do server related things like working with a blog system like Wordpress or similar. The you have to install a local webserver like Apache, a database, PHP (if you absolutely need to) and so on. All of that is combined into the aforementioned WAMP, LAMP, MAMP ... packages.

A great knowledge resource is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).